# Webpack failing to pack https from Nodejs in Electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron

My webpack config appears to successfully build, however i get undefined references to the https package despite defining the import in the config.

Im unsure if my webpack is incorrectly configured or if im somehow calling https incorrectly when defining the axios instance. any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

`webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "./build/app");
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/app");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: SRC_DIR + "/index.tsx",
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: BUILD_DIR,
  },
  resolve: {extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"]},
  module: {
    rules: [
      {test: /\.tsx?$/, include: SRC_DIR, use: "awesome-typescript-loader"},
      {test: /\.(j|t)sx?$/, enforce: "pre", use: "source-map-loader"},
      {test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]},
      {test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, use: "url-loader?limit=100000"},
      {test: /\.html$/, use: "html-loader"},
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/app/html/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html",
    }),
    new webpack.ExternalsPlugin("commonjs", ["electron", "https"]),
  ],
  target: "electron-renderer",
};
```

`Client Instance`

```js
import Axios from "axios";
import https from "https";

export const clientInstance = Axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://127.0.0.1:2999/liveclientdata/allgamedata",
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ // <---- this is where it fails. the reference to https.
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  }),
});
```

`error`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.https (bundle.js:7743)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:7766)
    at eval (webpack://express-electron-core/./src/app/components/plugins/axios.ts?:9)
    at Object../src/app/components/plugins/axios.ts (bundle.js:316)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:7766)
    at eval (webpack://express-electron-core/./src/app/components/hooks/useAssociatedAccounts.ts?:5)
    at Object../src/app/components/hooks/useAssociatedAccounts.ts (bundle.js:173)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:7766)
    at eval (webpack://express-electron-core/./src/app/components/hooks/index.ts?:4)
    at Object../src/app/components/hooks/index.ts (bundle.js:140)
```

Comment: The https library is just there on node, it is not packed by webpack ever. Are you trying to use axios in the browser?

Comment: @trognanders no, in an electron window.

Answer (score 0):

`main.ts`

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences:{
    contextIsolation: true //this was the issue
  }
});
```